# REST Post API - retrieve result from TinyURL method

Tags: node.js, express, rest, tinyurl

I failed to get a result from TinyURL within the POST method and assign it to "short_url" for the response. The console.log(short_url) will show "Promise { pending }". I tried async / await function to retrieve the TinyURL result but I'm sure I'm not using it right.

```
var express = require('express')
var TinyURL = require('tinyurl')

var app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.post('/api/shorturl', (req, res) => {

  let original_url = req.body.url
  console.log(original_url) // this one shows correct URL from request body

  async function createShortURL(url) {
    await TinyURL.shorten(url, function(res) {
    console.log(res) // this one shows correct shortened URL
  }
  )}

  let short_url = createShortURL(original_url)
  console.log(short_url) // this one shows "Promise { <pending> }"

  res.json({
    original_url : original_url,
    short_url : short_url
  })

})

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing async/await and callback. Don't do that. The [tinyurl library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinyurl) provides the Promise version of `shorten` method. We can use async/await directly.

```
app.post('/api/shorturl', async (req, res) => {

  let original_url = req.body.url
  console.log(original_url) // this one shows correct URL from request body

  // just this
  let short_url = await TinyURL.shorten(url);
  console.log(short_url)

  res.json({
    original_url : original_url,
    short_url : short_url
  })

})
```

---

**EDIT**
If you're using callback, please be aware of [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). It's one of the main reasons why people prefer async/await.

Comment: I edited my answer :) Hope you will find something interesting in the link

Comment: This is great! Thanks! I understand "await" is for the TinyURL to finish its process. But why do you need it in this case for it to work? I'll look into the async / callback link you provided

Comment: I just follow the documentation. `shorten` is an asynchronous function so we need to use `await`, to wait for it finishes. If you look at the source code, it calls the API of `https://tinyurl.com/` to do the job, and network requests are asynchronous.

Comment: I couldn't see the "await" in the TinyURL documentation. It does show callback function in the shorten method. Is that what you meant? It's cool, I didn't know you can replace the callback function with "await". Is that right?

Comment: No no, they are 2 things different. You can only use async/await if the method provides a **Promise** version. async/await is just a sugar syntax to write Promise-based code. On the npm page, you can see the `// Promise Example` part